# Get friend's gender in a Facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

While developing a Facebook application I got the friendlist of a user by

> $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

But I only got to know the name and Facebook Ids of the friends : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList

Is there any way to get the gender of a friend?

One way to do so is to get the user's gender (since it is publicly available) given the user's facebook Id (which I have got using the friend list)

Is it really possible to do the above thing.
If not is there any other way?

for reference : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: do answer if its not possible to do it

Comment: You can do it by using nested fql query.
see this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307381/sql-query-to-fetch-users-facebook-friend-list-based-upon-gender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList = a persons fiend lists (plural) - eg: Limited Profile

What you want to do is get the ID from graph.facebook.com/me/firends and then do a graph.facebook.com/ID for the gender. But of course that ends up being a lot of requests if you need it for all of their friends.

For those cases you can use FQL query: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

You can adopt following query from their documentation:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Here name and gender of the current users friends:

```
SELECT uid, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Comment: no I need only a particular friend's gender (selected using some algorithm) so your first approached worked). I figured it out myself only but when I came back to post my answer , I saw yours there so I don't need to write again. Anyways loved your FQL query approached though.

Answer (score 4):

A quick way with **Graph API**

```
$facebook->api('me/friends?fields=id,name,gender,installed&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]");
```

Comment: Do you need to pass the access token? Won't the $facebook->api call do that for you?